# Python + Scattergraphs + Other Nonsense

Tags: python, math, statistics, machine-learning, data-extraction

I receive a fair few emails a week detailing abusive activity originating from a network that I am involved with. These usually contain either:

a) A URL deemed as being compromised.

or

b) A copy of an email that is considered spam.

Most of these are automated, and typically don't follow the ARF very well.

What I need is automated data extraction, but I am racking my head because I am not so sure how to do it when the structure of the email is changing and unpredictable.

What I am looking to extract at the moment is:

a) Originating Mail Servers for Spam (And also the UID/Username, which is shown in most Exim/Qmail Received Headers)

b) Domain Names

c) URLs for compromised sites

d) Email Addresses

I can do this with no sweat using some regexes and a bit of other junk, but basically it is unreliable. By parsing the email body I may end up with 5 IPs, 3 URLs, and 3 email addresses, and I am unsure of how to automatically pick the best fit.

I need some direction as to what I should be researching/looking for in order to make the best automatic judgement about what the correct data is. I have over 100,000 past report emails, so there is no shortage of test data, I just need to know how to get started and what I should be looking into to solve this problem.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, please let me know if I have missed something or if there are other questions :)

FYI, I have considered the following:

- Insersecting several past emails from this sender that have been classified, and then doing a set difference against the new email. I have no idea on the best way to do this though apart from hardcoding some algorithms using python sets + lists.
- Plotting all my previous data onto various forms of ScatterPlot/Histogram. I would then be able to test each new email against the existing data and pick out the details that are least prevailant within the graph. Once again, I am not sure of what libraries I should be looking for here.
- Using the sample data to put a weight against previously seen items. I.e. If I put up a page of 1000 previous samples, and 'mark-down' the IPs which are never going to be correct, and marking up IPs that could be correct.
- Writing a tangle of code involving socket lookups to resolve hostnames and match items together. I know that this will be intensive to run, but it will most likely get the best results.

Cheers!

Comment: I doubt there's a simple approach that will give you excellent results, but I'd try writing something to detect the pattern of forwarded email. Most email software adds very predictable features to forwarded messages, and identifying such a message would give *context* to the UIDs/URLs/domains/addresses you can already extract.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with some of the ideas you've already considered.

First you'll need to construct a sample data set that's "truth" or properly classified already, and which lists the offending IP, URL, email address, etc.  So define some categories and some relevant data and plow through it.  It's not fun, but it's necessary.

At this point you can decide if you want to just go Bayesian and see how it works, or you can do feature engineering and try other methods.

Bayesian classification is a black box that you feed a bunch (say 1/2 or 2/3) of your test data into and then try it on there rest to see how the trained classifier works.  If you get something in the 90% plus range you're essentially done, provided that it's fast enough.  The one feature you should output is every "token" in the email.  Split on whitespace.  You can start here:

http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.classify-module.html

If you decide to do feature engineering, now you enter the exploratory phase.  Whenever you're doing machine learning or pattern classification you need to define "features" which you can extract from the source data.  As you said you can use regexes to get email addresses, IPs, and URLs.  Those are all excellent features.  What other features might you be able to find?  Perhaps some of the timestamps (are there temporal relationships?  Who knows?).  Some of the email headers might be useful, like MIME version, SenderID, ContentType, X-Spam-Level, the charset, etc.

Once you have decided upon some features that you personally use to help determine what's going on, then you can use the same bayesian classifier listed above to teach the computer how to make these decisions.

With a bunch of new features defined you can run the training on 50% and then evaluate the results against the other 50% to see how it performed.  If you get a high level of accuracy, great!  You're done.  If it's still low you'll need to define other features to help the classifier discriminate properly.  Only you will be able to decide how high is high and how low is low.